# Exclude the "already" visible divs after page load, from being animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the follwing code which animates some divs thru adding an animation class to them when they come into browser window.

My only problem comes with the divs that are "already" visible in the screen after page load, once I do a little scroll they animate.

What is the best way to exclude the divs that are "already" visible in the browser window after page load?

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function checkAnimation_aec() {
    var $elem = $('.aec');
    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return;
    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('icon_start');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events & run the functions
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(window).scroll(function(){
          checkAnimation_aec();
      });

});
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function checkAnimation_aec() {
    var $elem = $('.aec');
    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('icon_start')) return;
    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('icon_start');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events & run the functions
$(document).ready(function(){

          //after document is ready, run the animation element is visible.
          checkAnimation_aec();  

      $(window).scroll(function(){
          checkAnimation_aec();
      });

});
```